# Why is this way of reading from a NetworkStream so much faster?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, networking

At my company we've run into an issue that we cannot seem to explain. We're reading from a `NetworkStream` using a buffer of 2048 bytes. When both the client and server use that buffersize to write and read with, it's hideously slow (1 second extra on top of other processing times). If we use a buffersize that's very large, like 32k everything works really fast. The message we're sending is usually much larger than 32k so the entire message does not entirely fit in that buffer. The way we're reading is shown in the code below in the `HandleDataLargeBuffer` method.

To build a testcase for this issue I've written the code below, and I've posted my output below that.

My questions:

- Any idea why a larger buffer size would be faster (less read calls but those shouldn't take too much time)?
- In the code below, `HandleDataVariableBuffer` is much much faster than the other methods of reading, why?
- Which is the best way of reading anyway?

Using a Proxy class to simulate slowdowns, pasted below the main file.

```
    class Program
    {
        private StreamWriter Writer;
        private int Count = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program();
        }

        public Program()
        {
            Writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Create));
            Start();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Proxy p = new Proxy();

            new Thread(p.Start).Start();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            new Thread(SetupServer).Start();

            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for TCP Server setup.
            for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 50001);
                Send(client.GetStream());
                client.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }


            WriteLine("Tests done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Writer.Close();
        }

        private void SetupServer()
        {
            WriteLine("[Server] Starting server.");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 50000);
            listener.Start();

            WriteLine("[Server] Started listening on port 50000.");
            while (true) // We'll just forcibly end, obviously you'd use the callback methods for this normally.
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                WriteLine(String.Format("[Server] Accepted client with IP: {0}", client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));
                new Thread(HandleClient).Start(client);
            }
        }

        private void HandleClient(object argument)
        {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)argument;
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Now there are multiple ways to handle this data, however first we read the int at the start.
            byte[] length = new byte[4];
            stream.Read(length, 0, 4);

            int lengthInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(length, 0);

            if (lengthInt <= 0) return; // Shouldn't happen.

            // Test data read in multiple ways.
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            string handler = "";
            if (Count == 0)
            {
                handler = "LargeBuffer";
                HandleDataLargeBuffer(lengthInt, stream);
                ++Count;
            }
            else if (Count == 1)
            {
                handler = "SmallBuffer";
                HandleDataSmallBuffer(lengthInt, stream);
                ++Count;
            }
            else if (Count == 2)
            {
                handler = "VariableBuffer";
                HandleDataVariableBuffer(lengthInt, stream);
                Count = 0;
            }
            watch.Stop();

            WriteLine(String.Format("\t[Server] [{3}] Read {0} bytes from client {1} in {2} ms", lengthInt.ToString(), client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), handler));
        }

        private void HandleDataLargeBuffer(int length, NetworkStream stream)
        {
            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;

            MemoryStream dataBuffer = new MemoryStream(); // I'm writing to a memory stream because in my real life situation I write (stream) to another NetworkStream
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192 * 4];
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 8192 * 4)) != 0 && totalRead < length)
            {
                totalRead += read;
                dataBuffer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        private void HandleDataSmallBuffer(int length, NetworkStream stream)
        {
            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;

            MemoryStream dataBuffer = new MemoryStream(); // I'm writing to a memory stream because in my real life situation I write (stream) to another NetworkStream
            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 512)) != 0 && totalRead < length)
            {
                totalRead += read;
                dataBuffer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        private void HandleDataVariableBuffer(int length, NetworkStream stream)
        {
            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;

            MemoryStream dataBuffer = new MemoryStream(); // I'm writing to a memory stream because in my real life situation I write (stream) to another NetworkStream

            while (totalRead < length)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length - totalRead]; // You'd obviously do some additional checks on 'length' to make sure no foul play is involved.
                read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, length - totalRead);
                totalRead += read;

                dataBuffer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        public void Send(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            // Generate some random data
            Random r = new Random();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 420]; // Buffer of 420k to simulate a decently large message
            byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(1024 * 420);
            r.NextBytes(buf);

            // Create the total message array: [Length][Message]
            byte[] totalMessage = new byte[4 + 1024 * 420];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(length, 0, totalMessage, 0, 4);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buf, 0, totalMessage, 4, buf.Length);


            // Use a memory stream for ease of use
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(totalMessage))
            {
                int read = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                while ((read = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
            stream.Flush();
            watch.Stop();

            WriteLine("[Send] Took " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms to send " + totalMessage.Length + " bytes of data.");
        }

        public void WriteLine(string str)
        {
            Writer.WriteLine(str);
            Writer.Flush();
        }
    }
```

**Proxy.cs**

```
public class Proxy
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 50001);
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();


                new Thread(HandleClient).Start(client);
            }
        }

        private void HandleClient(object argument)
        {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)argument;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            int read = 0;
            byte[] length = new byte[4];
            clientStream.Read(length, 0, 4);

            int lengthInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(length, 0);
            if (lengthInt <= 0)
            {
                client.Close();
                return;
            }

            TcpClient serverClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 50000);
            NetworkStream serverStream = serverClient.GetStream();

            int totalRead = 0;

            serverStream.Write(length, 0, 4);

            while (totalRead < lengthInt)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[lengthInt - totalRead]; // You'd obviously do some additional checks on 'length' to make sure no foul play is involved.
                read = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, lengthInt - totalRead);
                totalRead += read;


                serverStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            serverStream.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            client.Close();
            serverClient.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry for the heap of code posted, when I first started I hoped it'd be smaller. Here's the output on my machine.

```
[Server] Starting server.
[Server] Started listening on port 50000.
[Server] Accepted client with IP: 127.0.0.1:3985
[Send] Took 1047 ms to send 430084 bytes of data.
    [Server] [LargeBuffer] Read 430080 bytes from client 127.0.0.1:3985 in 1148 ms
[Server] Accepted client with IP: 127.0.0.1:3987
[Send] Took 1049 ms to send 430084 bytes of data.
    [Server] [SmallBuffer] Read 430080 bytes from client 127.0.0.1:3987 in 1150 ms
[Server] Accepted client with IP: 127.0.0.1:3989
[Send] Took 1051 ms to send 430084 bytes of data.
    [Server] [VariableBuffer] Read 430080 bytes from client 127.0.0.1:3989 in 100 ms
Tests done.
```

Comment: If the latency had been 200ms I had said that it's nagling... Still, try to set `Socket.NoDelay = true`.

Comment: That's some confusing code. Are you writing to the proxy and then the proxy writes to the client, which reads? Testing through the loopback interface is going to give skewed results. You should split this program into a server piece and a client piece, and then test over a network with the server and client on separate machines. As it currently exists there are several possible bottlenecks. Simplify the test so that you can reduce the number of possible culprits.

Comment: Wots with all the Thread.Sleep() calls?  Are you addicted to them?  Maybe you should join InappropriateUseOfSleeps Anonymous:)  Get rid of the one in the read() loop, to start with.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to simulate network latency by using the Proxy and Sleeps. Right now, the client sends to proxy which sends to server. That's all, no return responses.